# How to setup multiple IPs on using single NIC

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

I to setup multiple IPs on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 server. I have it in a data center and they gave me 5 IPs range 170-174.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create aliases of your network interface.

- By creating temporary aliases using `ip address add` command. The aliases setup this way will be lost upon a reboot and you will need to recreate those aliases.

  ```
  sudo ip addr add xx.xx.xx.xx/xx dev eth0

  # For example

  sudo ip addr add 172.16.100.170/24 dev eth0
  ```
- If you need a more permanent solution, you would have to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add alias definitions there.

Then use `ip addr show` command to see the changes. Then you would have to do `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` to activate these settings without a reboot.

Comment: Ok so I did this and 4 out of the 5 ips work. The only work not working is 171. It is a /29 ip

Comment: since you wanna use /29, `2**(32-29) - 2 = 2**3 - 2 = 8 - 2 = 6` that means only 6 hosts are allowed to use.

Comment: You do think its a problem with the hosting company because I added all of them but 171 is not working but others work and have no problems.

Comment: The way I have done this in the past is with ifconfig. "ifconfig eth0:1 172.16.100.171 netmask 255.255.255.0 up". You can add virtual adapters on the real interface by adding colon and then a number.